# Определение нажатого элемента

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, dom

Здравствуйте, мне нужно как то определить на каком элементе я кликнул. Элемент может быть вообще любым. Т.е. у меня допустим есть на странице 5 элементов совершенно разных, и я кликаю по любому из элементу и мне высвечивается его класс или какой-то атрибут... Также элементы могут быть удалены или добавлены со страницы... Т.е. чтобы куда бы я не кликнул он мне всё равно вернул элемент, по которому я кликнул. И самое главное, это если элемент находится в другом элементе, то при нажатии на него возвращался этот элемент а не его родитель... Может быть не понятно. Если что спрашивайте (если что-то не поняли).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('body').click(function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
});​
```

Answer (score 7):

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.onclick = function(event) {
         t=event.target||event.srcElement; 
         alert(t.tagName);
    }
}
```